# Why can't I wrap a series of <li>'s in a tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know how to do this with jQuery, but I want to learn it with vanilla javascript, I have a feeling it'll be faster. Here's a link to jsFiddle with a stripped down version of what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/yramagicman/MyM2B/ and below is the offending script.

```
<script>
var id = 'ul';
var tag = 'li';
var wrapTag = 'span';
var wrapper = document.createElement(wrapTag);
var z = document.getElementById(id);
var y = z.getElementsByTagName(tag);
var count = y.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    y[i].setAttribute("class", "red"); //so I can see the result
    wrapper.appendChild(y[i].cloneNode(true));
    y[i].parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, y[i]);
    wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'hi'); //so I can see the result
}</script>
<!-- and the html-->
<ul id="ul" class="ul">
    <li class="li">1</li>
    <li class="li">2</li>
    <li class="li">3</li>
    <li class="li">4</li>
    <li class="li">5</li>
    <li class="li">6</li>
    <li class="li">7</li>
    <li class="li">8</li>
</ul>
```

I can wrap the entire Ul in a div or span or whatever just fine but when I try to wrap each list item I get the error "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong." Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the HTML for the desired result.   We don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  As it is, it looks like you are trying to put an `<li>` into a `<span>` which is not allowed.  You can put a `<span>` into an `<li>`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building an invalid DOM. `<li>` must belong in `<ul>` or `<ol>` but you're trying to place it in a `<span>`. Hence the error: *"A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong"*.

Answer (score 2):

flem's answer is not correct. Although an `<li>` element is not valid as child of a `<span>` element in any version of HTML, it should not be an issue for the DOM and in fact is not.

There are two key pieces of information you need to understand. The first is that the node list returned by `getElementsByTagName` is a live list attached to the DOM document. If the JS loop changes the DOM document, then the list gets updated.

The second is that you are creating the wrapper element once but using it with replaceChild each time around the loop.

So the first time around the loop everything works fine. The second time around the loop, the cloned element gets added to the wrapper, which is now in the DOM document and so becomes the second element in the `y` node list.

So `y[i]` is no longer the source `<li>` but the instead it's the cloned element and hence`y[i].parentNode` is the wrapper element.

This means that on the replaceChild line, your code is attempting to make the wrapper element a child of itself. This is impossible, hence HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR